# about the break statement

Tags: c, break

I'm kind of confused about the `break` statement

If I have for example a `for` loop inside a `while` loop and there is a `break` inside the for loop:

the `break` statement will break out of the `while` loop right?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You can read more about the `break` statement semantics [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.8.6.3).

Comment: In order to break nested loops in C you use `goto label`. A break, can only break one level of loop, not nested loops. For example if you need to jump out of both from inside the `for` loop you can use `while (..) {for (..) { if (condition) goto done; } } done:;`

Comment: In order to break nested loops in C, you *can* use `goto label`... or you can put the loops into a subfunction, and `return` from the function when you want to break out, which some[citation needed] consider the "cleaner" approach.

Comment: This question has been through successive edits to gradually make it more confusing. `break`, as any other statement, does what the language creators decide. I can make my own language and decide what `break` will close a window.

Comment: my point is that the break statement seems to do the same thing in the same pattern in no matter which language is used

Answer (score 6):

No, the break statement will break out of the for loop. The break statement is used to exit the loop it is written in

Answer (score 1):

The `break` statement in C programming has the following two usages:

- When a `break` statement is encountered inside a loop, the loop is immediately terminated and the program control resumes at the next statement following the loop.
- It can be used to terminate a `case` in the `switch` statement

If you are using nested loops, the `break` statement will stop the execution of the innermost loop and start executing the next line of code after the block.

[Have a look here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_break_statement.htm)

Comment: A *block* a list of statements or declarations inside `{` and `}`. A `break` exits the innermost loop and continues execution after that loop, not necessarily after any block—a loop may be written without a block for its body.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `break` will exit the loop it's written in for example:

```
int main(void) {
  int i=0;
  int for_called_count=0;

  while(i<10){
    for_called_count++;
    for(int j=1; j<=10; j++){
      i++;
      if(j==5){
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("i: %i", i);
  printf("\nfor_called_count: %i", for_called_count);
}
```

Output:

```
i: 10
for_called_count: 2
```

Here you see, `for` is called twice because once the `for loop` exits with `break`, the `while loop` is not done as i is still smaller than 10 so it calls for again. That shows that `break` only exits the loop it's written in.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` will only exit the `for loop`, and will proceed again in `while loop` if the condition in `while loop` is still not met